# Control Text Box control's Text in D365

Tags: javascript, textbox, dynamics-crm, multiline, dynamics-365

1. I have a requirement in Dynamics 365 online to control the behavior of a multiline textbox which stores call script messages.
2. There is a drop-down list on the form which populates the call script messages on to the text box when the user selects some options.
3. User can then edit these populated messages in the text box. Later if the user decides to remove some options or add some options from the drop-down, the respective messages should be deleted from the textbox.

I know this can be accomplished using html by tagging each text related to the option in the rich text box but not sure how this can be accomplished in D365 in a supported way?

Can it be done using some scripting or can it be done using web resource embedded on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way. Source field is dropdown, destination field is multiline textbox where content has to be populated based on option selected in dropdown.

1. This can be done by having some placeholder markers & replace the dynamic text. But this is too complex to maintain
2. Just furnish this using `onChange` script of dropdown, you can have some configuration entity to store the pre-defined text for each dropdown option, just pull the respective content on the change of dropdown option & concatenate/replace the content of multiline with retrieved configuration text

Comment: Yes there is a configuration entity to store the pre-defined text but problem is removing the text which was un-selected by the user from the dropdown.

Comment: @AJunkie can you take the existing content & replace or build the script text based on current selection.. its a broad topic. if you share specific code what you tried, can take it from there..